# Create a view in SQL

Tags: sql, view

I want to create a view from this:

```
select  sph.SiProforma,SuProforma,cps.Tp_FamilyOffice_Name,DsProforma,NaProformaFee,NqCount,NaProformaFee*NqCount as jameradif,
        SUM(NaProformaFee*NqCount)OVER(PARTITION BY suProforma) AS ghabelepardakht,ssv.Tp_Code_Desc,DsContract,proj.TpProject,
        Status.Tp_Code_Desc,spd.SiGoods,CtbGdsSpc2.TpGds,ctbgdsspc2.CuGds,Ds_Edit,ctbservice.TpService
from Sls.SlsProformaHeader sph 
    inner join dbo.Ctb_Persons_Specifications cpson sph.SiPerson=cps.Si_Person 
    inner join sls.SlsProformaDetail spd on sph.SiProforma=spd.SiProforma 
    inner join Sls.SlsProformaStatusV Status ON sph.SiProformaStatus = Status.Cu_Code 
    inner  join dbo.CtbProject2 Proj ON Proj.SiProject = sph.SiContract 
    left outer join CtbService on spd.SiService=ctbservice.SiService
    left outer join CtbGdsSpc2 on spd.SiGoods=CtbGdsSpc2.SiGds 
    left outer join dbo.Ctb_Code_Details det ON sph.SiComplimentory = det.Si_Code 
    left outer join Sls.SlsSaleTypeV ssv on spd.sisaletype =ssv.si_code
```

I wrote create view el as..., but it gave me this error:

> Msg 4506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure el, Line 1
>   Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'Tp_Code_Desc' in view or function 'el' is specified more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including two columns called `Tp_Code_Desc` in the view. Column names need to be unique. So one of them should be given a different alias.